# How to manage tooltip jquery

Tags: jquery, tooltip

i'm developing a tooltip. It must show when i click on a href, and i want to hide it by clicking outside tooltip, or after a delay. i'm doing in this way:

```
$('#aiuti').qtip({
        content: {
            text: "In questa sezione e' possibile pianificare l'invio delle notifiche scegliendo Il Target degli utenti - il Tipo di notifica - Titolo della notifica - Il Messaggio - Periodicita' invio e date - inoltre la periodicita' e gli stati di invio possono essere verificati da apposito pannello con filtri di ricerca."
        },
        show: {
            event: 'click'
        },
        hide: {
            delay: 1000
        }
    }).click(function() {
        var _$this = $(this);

        if(_$this.html() === 'Attiva aiuti') {

            _$this.html('Chiudi aiuti');
        } else {
            _$this.html('Attiva aiuti');
        }
    })
```

In this way, if tooltip will hide after the delay, if i click again on link, tooltip is shown again. how can i do ? can you help me?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using any of the existing plugins that cover this? (Like self-learning, which is totally respectable)

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways:

The first the tooltip is hidden after the delay:

```
$('#aiuti').qtip({
   content: {
            text: "text text text"
    }
    ,show: {
        event: 'click',
        solo: true // Only show one tooltip at a time
    }
    ,hide: {
        delay: 1000
    }
}
```

Or after clicking outside the tooltip:

```
$('#aiuti').qtip({
    content: {
            text: "text text text"
    }
    ,show: {
        event: 'click',
        solo: true // Only show one tooltip at a time
    }
    ,hide: {
        event:'unfocus'
    }
}
```

Combining the two ways appears that doenst work, but you can try to find a solution in the [documentation](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/api/#methods)